# Attempting a formula that is just not cooperating

Tags: excel, error-handling, ref

Working on a bit of code to get a Health section in a D&D related excel document to recognize class and add appropriate health amounts in its stead, but I keep getting a #REF! error and I can't seem to figure it out.
I'll admit I'm not...confident in my abilities with formulas but I'm using another thing that does the same thing as a reference and THAT works while this doesn't so. Help?

```
=IF('Character Basics'!D13(VLOOKUP('Character Basics'!D13,"Rogue",TRUE))=TRUE,25,IF('Character Basics'!D13(VLOOKUP('Character Basics'!D13,"Warrior",TRUE))=TRUE,30,IF('Character Basics'!D13(VLOOKUP('Character Basics'!D13,"Mage",TRUE))=TRUE,20)))+D4
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your formulas makes no sense. First part, `IF('Character Basics'!D13(VLOOKUP('Character Basics'!D13,"Rogue",TRUE))=TRUE,25,...` What are you trying to achieve here?Also, your `Vlookups` are not right. Check the argumens for [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1). Also, if you have named rangues like `Rogue, Warrior, Mage` you must invoke them without the double quotes `"`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Like I said, not confident in my abilities, haha. Basically what i'm going for is: If the class Rogue is selected it adds 25 to the box. If Warrior, 30, etc.

Comment: Can you post a data example? The input you got and the expeced output

Comment: Iiii continued fiddling, and worked on another formula for a while to clear my head and apparently I was just being too difficult. So after 1.Naming the Class area and 2, calming the heck down I ended up with<br>```=IF(Class="Rogue",25,IF(Class="Warrior",30,IF(Class="Mage",25)))+D4``` and it's worked! :)